# Colliding Monads (Text.JSON.Result & Maybe), how to solve

Tags: haskell

The below code incorporates the use of 2 monads, and in some fashion, I need to wind and wend the actual data through the types in `read_field`.

What I'd like to do is be able to extract the String from the Result monad (if OK), and then pass it into `get_field`, then as it comes out, wrap it in Result and send on to main for either printing or erroring.

```
module Main where
import System.IO
import System.Environment
import Text.Printf
import Text.JSON.Generic
import Text.JSON.Types
import Text.JSON

touchJSONfile path = do
  -- Touches a file into existence. The good touch.
  writeFile path "{}\n"
  return ()


read_field :: String -> String -> IO String
read_field filename key = do
  result <- readFile filename
  let json_data = decode result :: Result JSValue
  value <- json_data >>= \x -> get_field x key     -- right here
  return (value)



main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  case head args of
    "init-store" ->  touchJSONfile (args !! 1)
    "set-keyf" -> putStrLn $ show args  --stub
    "set-keyi" -> putStrLn $ show args  --stub
    "get-key" -> putStrLn $ read_field ( args !! 1 )  (args !! 2)
    _ -> putStrLn "Error, command not accepted"

  return ()
```

Comment: The `return ()` in main isn't needed; also, you can finish `read_field` with just `json_data >>= ...`; there's no need for using return.  It's also convention in Haskell to use camelCase rather than underscores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm making a few assumptions.  The text in your json file must be:

```
{ "somekeyyousearchfor : "somevalueyouwant" }
```

In which case, let's do this step by step.  First we have a result:

```
read_field filename key = do
  result <- readFile filename
  let res = decode result :: Result JSValue
```

Result is either Ok JSValue or Error String, so:

```
read_field filename key = do
  result <- readFile filename
  let json_data = decode result :: Result JSValue
  return $ case res of
    Error e -> ""
    Ok json_data -> undefined
```

So far so good.  Now we have json_data which is a JSValue.  The input we have is an object so:

```
read_field filename key = do
    result <- readFile filename
    let json_data = decode result :: Result JSValue
    return $ case res of
      Error e -> ""
      Ok json_data -> case json_data of
        JSObject ob -> undefined
        _ -> ""
```

Okay, now we have a JSObject, where ob is a JSObject JSValue.  This JSObject is a new type, not a constructor like the previous, but can use the get_field function on it, so:

```
read_field filename key = do
  result <- readFile filename
  let json_data = decode result :: Result JSValue
  return $ case res of
    Error e -> ""
    Ok json_data -> case json_data of
      JSObject ob -> case (get_field ob key) of
        Just (JSString str) -> ""
        _ -> ""
      _ -> ""
```

It returned Just JSValue, and since we are assuming it wil be a string, we don't care about any other values.  So it is JSString, which is a wrapper around a normal string so:

```
read_field :: String -> String -> IO String
read_field filename key = do
  result <- readFile filename
  let res = decode result :: Result JSValue
  return $ case res of
    Error e -> ""
    Ok json_data ->
      case json_data of
        JSObject ob -> case (get_field ob key) of
          Just (JSString str) -> fromJSString str
          _ -> ""
        _ -> ""
```

Kind of annoying, but there is another library called aeson which does things very differently, and is a little more compact but is a little more complicated too.  There's a good example of how to use it on the haskell-beginners list that I posted recently.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
read_field :: String -> String -> IO String
read_field filename key = do
  result <- readFile filename
  case decode result of
    OK value  -> get_field value key
    Error err -> error err -- Do something with the error case; for now, kill the program.
```